# Importing .css into html document

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS/HTML and am trying to import a simple css class into the html document, but something appears to have gone awry. Here is Logo.css:

```
.logo{
  color:rgb(255,232,57);
  background-color:rgb(0,0,75);
  font:ChopinScript;
  font-size:96pt;
}
```

and my html document:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Logo.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<div class="logo">
  <p class="logo">This text should look like my logo!</p>
</div>
<img src="404-tumblebeast.jpeg" align=center valign=center />
```

The image shows up fine in Safari, but the text is just generic text. Does the link tag not import as I thought? How would I do the equivalent of #import or #include, if  isn't taking care of that?

Comment: Does the bg color change correctly? Or does it just not load your css at all?

Comment: nothing happens at all! Well the picture shows up and the text does, but nothing from my .css

Comment: Does your file exist? Is it served with the right mime-type (`text/css`)?

Comment: First chunk of code was Logo.css, second was 404.html (which is what I'm running in Safari

Comment: @RobW Explain the second part. If the code I put above is all that is in Logo.css, do I need to specify what type it is? the .logo class obviously refers to text

Comment: @Chris Offer a link to your failing code (HTML linking to CSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

end the link tag (see below: the /> instead of >).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Logo.css" type="text/css"/>
```

**Verify that the Logo.css is in the same directory as the html file or use the correct path to the Logo.css file.**  Just in case you are doing this, you can't put the css under the WEB-INF directory.

You only need the class on the `div` element or on the `p` element, not both.

***Edit:***
I was poking around and found some info about embedding fonts in a page: http://jonrohan.me/guide/css/font-face/

Comment: Okay I deleted the class from the `p` element and added the end of the link tag but we are still rocking the default font/color/white background.

Comment: Yes they are sitting right next to each other in the same folder.

Comment: I'm a liar. One was created in another folder. So it now gets the colors and the size correct but not the font

Comment: Put the font inline (in the HTML page) to confirm that it works.

Comment: `<p font=ChopinScript>This text should look like my logo!</p>` did not change the font :(

Comment: It looks like ChopinScript is not available

Comment: Yes I downloaded it and installed the font. Do I need to import a font to CSS?

Comment: We are at the end of my knowledge.  I've never done anything with fonts.

Comment: your css code for font should look like 'font-family:ChopinScript;'

try it this way.

look here for more: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp)